# Varify Webhook Signing secret

Tags: validation, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am working with stripe and need to varify the signing secret provided by my customer

I have stored the siging secret provided by customer in my db.
As of moment, I am varifying the signing secret provided by the customer with the signing secret of webhook req and then proceeding and wanted to know If i can varify it before the webhook triggers (at the moment user provides me the siging secret)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to verify the correctness of a signing secret.